# cca ordiplot length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Tags: r

I am plotting a cca of species data (556 species) and environmental parameters (eiv) but I have problems adding the species names as labels in the plot. Species names are in the header row of the spec data frame.

The species data has 369 herb species, 135 moss species and 52 lichen species which I tried to mark differently in the plot:

```
cca1<- vegan::cca(log1p(spec), log1p(eiv))

col<-c(rep("grey", 369), rep("red", 135),rep("green",52))
shp<- c(rep(1, 369), rep(15, 135),rep(17,52))
cex<- c(rep(0.5, 369), rep(0.7, 135),rep(0.7,52))
lgd<- c(rep("Herbs", 369), rep("Mosses",135), rep("Lichen",52))
spnames<-colnames(spec[,1:556])

ordiplot (cca1, display = 'sp', type = 'n', main ="CCA Alpine Species using EIV" )
points(cca1, display = "species", cex = cex, pch = shp,  col = col, scaling=3)
text(cca1, display = "species",labels=spnames,scaling=3)
text(cca1, display = "bp", col = "grey40", cex = 0.8, scaling=3)
legend(x="topright", legend=unique(lgd), col = unique(col), pch = unique(shp))
```

when I run the 'text(cca1, display = "species",labels=spnames,scaling=3) command I get this error:

Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Could it have something to do with the 3 different species groups although they make 556 species together?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the species names need to be column names (vector names), not the names of rows. But the example you gave is not sufficient for me to really look into it. Could you next time, please, provide a small reproducible example of the problem. This also makes it easier to provide help and answer your question. If I quickly try to see what the issue is, I do not get a problem when I plot the results of the CCA, see the example below.

```
spec <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100))
for(i in 1:556){
  spec[,paste("sp",i)] <- rbinom(100,1,0.5)
}
#This is awkward, ignore this bad coding part
spec <- spec[-1]

eiv <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 100))
for(i in 1:10){
  eiv[,paste("var", i)] <- rnorm(100)
}
#again very akward
eiv <- eiv[-1]

cca1 <- vegan::cca(spec, eiv)

col<-c(rep("grey", 369), rep("red", 135),rep("green",52))
shp<- c(rep(1, 369), rep(15, 135),rep(17,52))
cex<- c(rep(0.5, 369), rep(0.7, 135),rep(0.7,52))
lgd<- c(rep("Herbs", 369), rep("Mosses",135), rep("Lichen",52))
spnames<-colnames(spec[,1:556])

ordiplot (cca1, display = 'sp', type = 'n', main ="CCA Alpine Species using EIV" )
points(cca1, display = "species", cex = cex, pch = shp,  col = col, scaling=3)
text(cca1, display = "species",labels=spnames,scaling=3)
text(cca1, display = "bp", col = "grey40", cex = 0.8, scaling=3)
legend(x="topright", legend=unique(lgd), col = unique(col), pch = unique(shp))
```

Also, displaying names of 556 species in a plot will not work out very well as you can seen in the results. This could be reduced with something like the orditorp function (https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/01/13/decluttering-ordination-plots-in-vegan-part-2-orditorp/), but I am not to familiar with it. Or, remove some species that do not occur very often. I guess this is necessary, since they influence the "explained variation" of your CCA anyhow. You could also address the numerical results of the CCA by looking at the species scores.

```
sum.cca <- summary(cca1)
sum.cca$species
```

Based on this you could select some species that have very distinct positions in relation to the most explanatory CCA axis and discuss this. Also, re-performing the CCA on these species can give a nicer plot, but is of course very biased, since you remove a large part of the species and produce a new CCA on the extremes. I would suggest to look first at the question you want to answer.

Hope this helps